# extracting HOUR from an interval in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I was wondering how to properly extract amount of hours between given 2 timestamps objects.

For instance, when the following SQL query gets executed:

```
    select x, extract(HOUR FROM x) as result
    from
    (select (TIMESTAMP'2021-01-22T05:00:00' - TIMESTAMP'2021-01-01T09:00:00') as x)
```

The `result` value is `20`, while I'd expect it to be `500`.

It seems odd to me considering that `x` value indicates the expected return value.

Can anyone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong and perhaps suggest additional way of query so the desired result would return?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to do the maths with this one as `datediff` in SparkSQL only supports days.  This worked for me:

```
SELECT (unix_timestamp(to_timestamp('2021-01-22T05:00:00') ) - unix_timestamp(to_timestamp('2021-01-01T09:00:00'))) / 60 / 60 diffInHours
```

My results (in Synapse Notebook, not Databricks but I expect it to be the same):

[image]

The `unix_timestamp` function converts the timestamp to a Unix timestamp (in seconds) and then you can apply date math to it.  Subtracting them gives the number of seconds between the two timestamps.  Divide by 60 for the number minutes between the two dates and by 60 again for the number of hours between the two dates.

Comment: seems bit long to me but as long as it gets the job done it's fine be my :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Might be worth checking if there’s something new in Spark 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `extract` only extracts the hour component of the interval. So in your case the difference is 20 days and 20 hours, so it gives you back 20 hours.

To add the date component you could do this:

```sql
select x, extract(HOUR FROM x) + (extract(DAY FROM x) * 24) as result
    from
(select (TIMESTAMP'2021-01-22T05:00:00' - TIMESTAMP'2021-01-01T09:00:00') as x)
```

Not sure if this is more convenient than the other answer, but it's a different approach to consider.